# Change permalink structure with htaccess - wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to change my old domain name to new domain. What I ask here is how to redirect permalink structure with htaccess from

http://www.OldDomain.com/postname/ to http://NewDomain.com/postid/postname/

/%postname%/ /%postid%/

Answer (score 0):

Straight answer is NO, you must not do this via .htaccess.

Wordpress already supports (and enforces) this permalink structure so it is much better and cleaner to goto Wordpress admin panel and change the permalink structure to `/%postid%/%postname%/` in the newer installation of Wordpress.

PS: Note that even if you rewrite these URLs differently via mod_rewrite, WP will enforce and expect this to whatever is defined in it permalink definition.